# Implement CalendarView application iOS SDK 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS development. there i tried to show iOS default CalendarView in my ViewController.now i'm getting Errors please find below the code i used.

```
viewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    UILabel *dateLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
-(IBAction) getSelection;

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSCalendar * calendar;
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () //Error : Missing '@end'

@end  //Error : Expected selector for objective c method

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize datePicker, dateLabel;

-(void)getSelection
{
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc]
                          initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US" ] ;

    NSDate *pickerDate = [datePicker date];
    NSString *selectionString = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [pickerDate descriptionWithLocale:usLocale]];
    dateLabel.text = selectionString;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

call getSelection method to viewDidLoad

```
 [self getSelection];
```